# How to distinguish same class names in different folder in kotlin multiplatform/native for swift?

Tags: swift, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

In my project there are 2600+ auto-generated files that I was adding to Kotlin Multiplatform project to generate a `.framework` for iOS, and use as a module for Android. But in those auto-gens, there are deeply nested files in different folders, with same class names. Kotlin works well because of namespaces separation, but the generated framework has there same names classes, mutated with underscore(`_`), seemingly randomly in every build. How can I avoid this? I can add annotations or any other addendum to the classes.

An example:
Two folder structure:
`Contacts -> People -> EmailAddress` and 
`User->EmailAddress` would generate `EmailAddress`, and `EmailAddress_` for swift.

Maybe there is something I can do in the `packForXCode` task, or some other processing. But I have not found anything regarding this problem yet.

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Currently the only option is to rename the classes in source code.
To reduce the impact of this change to the existing code consider using `typealias`, e.g.

for `Contacts -> People -> EmailAddress`:

```
class ContactsEmailAddress
typealias EmailAddress = ContactsEmailAddress
```

for `User -> EmailAddress`:

```
class UserEmailAddress
typealias EmailAddress = UserEmailAddress
```